# Filter by Price, change button label

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget, hook-woocommerce

I'm not really sure which plugin is this but I'm gonna take a risk asking. I already tried searching but I couldn't find a way to change the text of the button labeling `Filter`.

[image]

I wanted to change it to `Apply Filter` instead of `Filter`.

[image]

No available option in the widget, so I think some kind of `hook` can change it.

This question is particularly to `WordPress` and `Woocommerce`, I'm not sure though if it is part of Woocommerce but it is available in `Appearance` > `Widget`.

Comment: Can you consider using a different plugin for it? How about the docs of WooCommerce specifically to [woocommerce_product_filter_price] ? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/shortcodes/woocommerce_product_filter_price/

Comment: I wanted to skip installing different plugin if possible since the widget is already available and the function I needed is already present, just needed to change the text of the button. However, I already found that docs and I tried using the shortcode with the option `submit_button_label="Apply Filter"` but no, it's not working, the filter is not even showing, I think that shortcode is particularly to a different plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The widget uses the following template file, overwriting and editing it can be a solution

> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-widget-price-filter.php line: [30](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-widget-price-filter.php#L30)
>
> - The template for displaying product price filter widget.
> - This template can be overridden by copying it to **yourtheme/woocommerce/content-widget-price-filter.php**

Replace

```php
<button type="submit" class="button"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Filter', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
```

With

```php
<button type="submit" class="button"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Apply Filter', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
```

Comment: Ohh! You don't know how much time I spend searching for this, yet I still receive a down-vote for my question. What kind of humanity do we have for real? Thank you so much! Bless you, brother!